# Android SQLite External Query Tool

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Is there a way to connect to the SQLite database while the emulator is running and do manual queries against the database?

The following is a basic sequence of steps I'm looking to achieve:

1. Query user table.
2. Add a user via the program.
3. Query user table to verify add successful.

Comment: from adb shell, you can sqlite3 your database and interact with it from there. It is not recommended to write in it while your app may be writing as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, and there's even a guide [on the Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#sqlite).

> From an adb remote shell, you can use the sqlite3 command-line program
>   to manage SQLite databases created by Android applications.

Note that you can also copy the database file out of the emulator using DDMS, and then examine it with tools like [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/).

Comment: thanks a million for the link to SQLiteStudio... its going to be very useful.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore, because `sqlite3` is not installed on newer Android versions. I'm now trying to install it manually, so far no luck...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but if anyone still looking for this then Facebook Stetho is the best tool for debugging DB related stuff:
http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

Only downside is that you need to add a couple of line to your gradle script and application class. But well worth it.